# Does anyone know how to explain this formula or where it comes from? It's in regards to applying Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We start with some PDE such that:
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = f(x,y) =4; 0<x<1, 0<y<1$$
$$BCs: u(0,y) = y^2,u(1,y) = 1+y^2, \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ u(x,0) = x^2,u(x,1) = 1+x^2$$
The solution is: $$u(x,y) = x^2+y^2;0<x<1,0<y<1$$
When applying the BCs I came across several formulas which I do not understand being:

$$f(0,y) \leftarrow f(0,y) - \frac{u(0,y)}{h^2}\\ f(1,y) \leftarrow f(1,y) -\frac{u(1,y)}{h^2} \\f(x,0) \leftarrow f(x,0)-\frac{u(x,0)}{h^2}\\ f(x,1) \leftarrow f(x,1) - \frac{u(x,1)}{h^2}$$

I found them in a program which goes into the entire process of solving this specific example and it includes the application of its BCs: [here](https://atmos.uw.edu/%7Ebreth/classes/AM585/matlab/lect/pois_FD_FFT_2D.m). It's a very short and simple program which uses Fourier Transforms to solve the problem. It says in the comments that these equations "correct for Dirichlet BCs", but I don't know what that means. Hopefully someone here does.

The code up to the point where the confusion comes into play is:

```
  L = 1;        % Domain size
  Ne = 16;      % Extended-domain gridpoints...should be a power of 2
  h = 2*L/Ne;   % Grid spacing
  m = Ne/2 - 1; % Number of interior gridpoints in original domain

  x = h*(1:m);
  y = h*(1:m);
  
  f = 4*ones(m,m);
  
  % Correct for Dirichlet BCs
  u0y = y.^2;     % u(0,y) = y^2
  u1y = 1 + y.^2; % u(1,y) = 1+y^2
  ux0 = x.^2;     % u(x,0) = x^2
  ux1 = 1 + x.^2; % u(x,1) = 1+x^2
  f(:,1) = f(:,1) - ux0'/h^2; % f(x,0) 
  f(:,m) = f(:,m) - ux1'/h^2; % f(x,1)
  f(1,:) = f(1,:) - u0y/h^2;  % f(0,y)
  f(m,:) = f(m,:) - u1y/h^2;  % f(1,y)
```

I thought this might be coming from the 2nd order centered difference equation where for example the last line $f(1,x)$ would be:
$$f(1,y) = f(x_m,y_j) = u(x_m,y_j)_{xx}+u(x_m,y_j)_{yy} = \\ \frac{u(x_{m+1},y_j)-u(x_{m-1},y_j)}{h^2} + \\ \frac{u(x_{m},y_{j+1})-u(x_{m},y_{j-1})}{h^2} - \\ \frac{4u(x_m,y_j)}{h^2}$$ where I'm assuming it's 0 at $x_{m+1}$ since the function does not exist there, and I would sub in the BC value of $u(1,y) = 1+y^2$ for $u(x_m,y_j)$ but, I was unable to get the equation to reduce to this formula shown in the code so I don't think that's where it came from. If anyone has any ideas as to where this line comes from or what it means, please let me know.

If it helps, the following images, illustrate what happens to $f(x,y) = 4$ when these BCs are applied:

[image: Before BCs]
[image: After BCs]

Comment: While not referenced on Wikipedia, it was not uncommon for physicists and mathematicians to refer *the* Dirichlet and *the* Neumann boundary conditions as $f=0$ or $\nabla_n f = 0$, respectively, on the boundary. The code simply subtracts off the boundary conditions to achieve a function which is always $0$ on the boundary. The $h$ has nothing to with differentiation. Notice that the arguments for $f$ are in "units" of $1$ to $m$, as opposed to the "real" distance units of $x$ and $y$ which are multiplied by $h$. The dividing by $h^2$ brings us back to non dimensional units.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Couple silly questions: When you say "subtracts off", are you saying that the methodology being deployed, we always "subtract" the BCs off? As for the division, so if we were using a first order equivalent, we would simply divide the BC by h instead of h^2? I'm asking because I know nothing about this. Maybe the wiki article goes into more depth if you could provide a link

Comment: @NinadMunshi or nevermind, you said, "not referenced on Wikipedia". Sorry. Do you know where I could learn more about this method? And thank you!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the order (which is differentiation) to the best of my understanding of this code. The boundary conditions involve functions of $x^2$s and $y^2$s, so you would have to divide by $h^2$s to lose your dimensions.

Comment: And yes, whatever algorithm they implement solves *the* Dirichlet boundary conditions since there are easier (mathematical) algorithms to do so. There is a procedure to solve for the inhomogeneous part separately. The best references I can give you are any physics textbook on electromagnetism, or perhaps a PDE textbook for graduate level mathematicians. It's been a while since I was in school, I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful :/

Comment: @NinadMunshi You were plenty helpful as you basically answered the question. I just wanted to know if there was a method to the madness so to speak. From the linked program, If I plot the surface for u, the obtained solution is forced to 0 around the boundaries like you mentioned. I just don't have the repertoire of experience to know why. I'd have to see exactly why these modifications at the earlier steps eventually lead to this result or find a proof. If you find anything else you can tell me let me know and thank you for your time!

Comment: I changed your post to use left arrows where you had used "$=$" in mathematical notation, because you were using the common computer science meaning of changing the value of a variable, instead of the mathematical meaning of asserting the two sides represent the same value.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's the thing though, I'm not actually sure if they were formulas. I think they were simply re-assignment of values at those indices but I wrote them as formulas  due to my misunderstanding, but if that is the correct notation, then by all means go ahead.. I think It would be like if I had ```x = ones(1,10)``` and then I reassigned the first element to ```x(1) = x(1) - 1```.

Comment: In code, if an = sign occurs in a logical context (such as in an IF statement), then it bears its mathematical meaning, returning true if the two sides are the same value, false otherwise. But everywhere else, = means assignment, which is not a meaning it ever has in traditional mathematical notation except when defining a new variable. Most programming languages now use the convention that the logical/mathematical meaning is denoted by ==, while a single = always means assignment. In the copied code, = definitely means assignment.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah, that's right. Been a while since I had classes in coding. = is an assignment operator so if that's the correct notation for it, then that's always going to be the case regardless of intention. Thank you!

Comment: @NinadMunshi Did you ever manage to find one of your previous textbooks which touched on this methodology? I'd love to go ahead and purchase it as I'm sure it will contain plenty of other useful things in it for future reference. Thanks in advance!